# disqus SEO google crawler doesn't load comments

Tags: seo, disqus

I see in google webmaster

> We were unable to load Disqus. If you are a moderator please see our troubleshooting guide.

instead of comments.

But i read in the Internet, disqus comments are readable by google Crawler.

As i understand to show "We were unable to load..." google had to load js script, but for some reason couldn't get comments from disqus.

What is wrong? How to fix this? I am using https://github.com/cryogen-project/cryogen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disqus comments don't tend to get indexed by Google. This is because the comments are served in an iframe.

If you absolutely must have your comments indexed, you should use a native solution and not Disqus or Facebook comments as they don't actually sit on your website but are pulled in via an iframe.

Comment: Oh, so somebody mislead me in the Internet.
Is there something like disqus what i can use? I want use software like https://github.com/cryogen-project/cryogen. It is very similar to http://octopress.org/ but in diffrent language. I don't want use Wordpress, because of security reason. I preffer static pages on server side.

So is there any disqus alterative to support SEO?

Comment: What are your concerns with using WordPress comments? If it's simply due to spam, you can use anti-spam comments, such as Captcha or Math Comment Spam. If you want to allow 3rd-party network login, there are plugins for that too, and if you want to stop SEO spam, just remove the website field and hold all comments with links for approval before publishing

Comment: I don't want use wordpress, because of security reasons and no controll over script. I can't even know when blog is really hacked and from my experience if blog is popular it will be hack sooner or later. So i preffer static content where hack is impossible.

Anyway... i read something about google use content from iframe too and disqus is optimize for that, but... it doesn't work.

Comment: Google can index iframe content indeed, and it will index it when it wants to, to identify new pages and content. However, it often treats those pages as their own standalone versions rather than as part of the page the iframe is embedded in, so that really shouldn't be your option.